# Add Object to Embedded Array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

Here are the schema I have, I am exporting them as one model and importing in my routers file.

```
import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose';
//import  DateSchema from "./dateSchemaModel";

let DateSchemaModel : Schema = new Schema({
basicDate: String,
FY: String,
FQ: String,
CY: String,
CQ: String, 
PY: String,
PQ: String
})
let SupplierListSchema: Schema = new Schema({
name: 
{
type: String, 
required: true 
},
 price: 
{
type: Number,
required: true
},
dateObj: [DateSchemaModel]
});

export default model('SupplierList', SupplierListSchema);
```

Then I import this model in my router file as below.

```
 `import SupplierList from '../models/supplierListModel';`
```

and then I create a class in typeScript named SupplierListRouter which has routes for REST Calls.

```
class SupplierListRouter 
{
router: Router;
constructor()
{
this.router = Router();
this.routes();
}



public AddDateObj(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): void {
const supplierId: string = req.params.supplierId;
//Create an instance of the model and assign it to the found document and then do 
//the save and other operations. 
var foundSupplierObj = new SupplierList();
const basicDate: string  = req.body.dateObj.basicDate;

//First find the specific supplier 
SupplierList.findById(req.params.supplierId, 
function(err,foundSupplierObj){
  if (err) throw err;
  foundSupplierObj.newNestedDateObj.push(req.body);
  foundSupplierObj.newNestedDateObj.save(function(err,supplierObj){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log('Added a new dateObj');
    res.json(supplierObj);; 
  });

/* I tried this but this does not work.
  SupplierList.schema.methods.dateObj.push(req.body);
  SupplierList.schema.methods.dateObj.save(function(err,supplierObj){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log('Added a new dateObj');
    res.json(supplierObj);
  });
  */
});
}
```

And I am trying to add a new document in dateObj array. But I tried using push but that does not work and populate as well. I am not sure how to go about adding a new document as an embedded document in here. Any ideas about to solve this problem?

Comment: You really need to spend more time reading the documentation as your code is full of problems due to concepts you have misunderstood. There is no such property as `newNestedDateObj`. In fact drop your naming conventions altogther. Instead follow the patttern: `SupplierList.findById(req.params.supplierId,(err,supplierList) => { if (err) throw err; supplierList.dateObj.push(req.body); supplierList.save((err) => { if (err) throw err; res.json(supplierList); }) });` And really only a start.

Comment: Thank you. I am a very new to typeScript, mongoose and web dev in general. Yeah, I found a way to do this using push as well. Do you have any recommendation on how to get started/get better at this?